# shelf with only 1 bracket

Tags: shelving

I want to mount a piece of wood on 1 wrought iron bracket at the side of a framed window with the shelf running about 3 feet across the window and no bracket on the other side.  How can I determine how much weight it will hold with only 1 bracket.  I want to put plants on the shelf. (this is a picture window so I don't want the shelf do go across the entire window)

Comment: What is going to support the other side of the shelf?  What is under the shelf (how bad will it be if the shelf falls)?

Comment: nothing will support the other side.  The point of leverage will be the mounting of the  board on the bracket.  Can it work?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that a shelf with one bracket will provide a favorable outcome. (Have you ever seen one?) It's hard to say knowing nothing about the bracket, though.

Comment: Maybe I'm not picturing this correctly, but I'm seeing a 3ft long shelf with a bracket on one side and the other side just hanging there?  No, that's not going to work.

Comment: Too many variables to consider. How thick is the wood? What is the species of wood? How much will the wood overhang on each side of the bracket? We need specs on the bracket. How will the shelf attach to the bracket? How will the bracket attach to the wall?

Comment: You might as well ask how many clowns a unicycle can support. :P

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a physics question but to point you in the right place

Torque = radius x force

Torque it the twisting at the anchor point

Radius is the center of mass
So the further from your anchor the more torque

Force is lbf or just lbs will be fine for the application.

To find the centre of mass (radius) take your shelf and find the balance point. Probably the centre so 1.5'

Weigh it we'll say 10 lbs

Torque =1.5 feet x 10lbs
So 15 foot pounds torque.

Now you add what you want to put on your shelf but keep in mind that center of mass changes the farther out you go.

And you need to cross reference your iron to see its capabilities.